# is it possible to open angular 2 application in node webkit and explain how?

Tags: angular, node-webkit

is it possible to open angular 2 application in node webkit and explain how?

I installed angular 2 by using:

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

I developed a simple application.

```
ng serve --open
```

the application working well in chrome browser. I wanted to open the application on node webkit. I go for

```
npm install nodewebkit
```

node webkit suggested me to change the

```
   "scripts": {
    "start": "nodewebkit"
}
```

Now I tried with

```
npm start
```

It wont start the angular app.

How to handle this?

Comment: As mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/shama/nodewebkit), the `nodewebkit` package is deprecated and hasn't been updated for 3 years. Try the [`nw`](https://github.com/nwjs/npm-installer) package instead.

Comment: Also, you'll need to provide `nw` with a path to your Angular project's compiled files, rather than using `ng serve`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nwjs/npm-installer#usage).

Comment: Thank You. Thanks for Yr reply.

Answer (score 1):

There is a github repo with an example of doing it.
https://github.com/nwutils/nw-angular-cli-example

I was on ubuntu 20.04 and it worked for me out of the box.

Also you can check out https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/angular-cli-and-nwjs-for-development-49gl which gives you step by step instructions on how to create your app from scratch. Again that worked for me out of the box.

Note I was also using a native mode module (C++). To save others a bit of a headache, here's some typescript that shows how to get that loaded:

```
    const modulewrapper = window.nw.require('native/modulewrapper.node');
    this.wrapper = new modulewrapper.ModuleWrapper();
    <snip>
    // call wrapper functions as normal
    this.wrapper.foo()
```

Note: that the native directory holds the C++ module.